# How do I efficiently find the fastest segments from a sequence of distances and times?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

My input is a gpx-file containing a sequence of timestamped positions, like the one you'd get if you go for a run with a GPS and tell it to record your track.

The timestamped positions are not necessarily equal in distance from each other, or equal in time-delta between each other.

Given this input, I want to efficiently find the highest speed the gpx-file indicates for all different distances.

Example:

```
12:00:00 start
12:00:05 moved 100m
12:00:15 moved 100m
12:00:35 moved 200m
```

In this example the correct answer is:

```
20.0 m/s at 100m
13.3 m/s at 200m
11.4 m/s at 400m
```

What is a good algorithm for (preferably reasonably efficiently) calculating this?

Clarification: I'm not looking solely for the fastest segment, that's trivial. I'm looking for the fastest speed represented by the track for ALL distances up to the length of the track in sum total.

If someone uploaded a gpx-track of a marathon they ran, I'd want to know the fastest 100m they ran in that marathon, the fastest 200m, the fastest 300m and so on.

Comment: What will you do when the gpx file doesn't have entries exactly every 100m? At least with the gpx files from my bicycle computer, the data points aren't on nice perfect boundaries like that. You might get a point at 100m, another at 219m, one at 297m, etc. Are you going to interpolate the incoming data and provide approximate 100m segments?

Comment: The answer I'm looking for here only needs to give the answer for the distances that exist. 

If I needed the fastest 300m and I only really know the fastest speed over 200m and over 400m, I guess the conservative estimate would be to say that whatever speed someone can maintain for 400m, they can certainly ALSO maintain over 300m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a gpx track for a 1,500 meter run, and you want to do this. So you want the fastest 100, 200, 300, 400, ... 1,500 meters. There are:

```
15 100-meter segments
14 200-meter segments
13 300-meter segments
12 400-meter segments
...
 2 1,400-meter segments
 1 1,500-meter segment
```

That works out to 15+14+13+12+...2+1 = (15^2-15)/2, or 105 different segments to examine if you want to calculate the 15 different distances.

You can do this in a single pass of the array. Simply initialize an array that contains the current running total and maximum speed for each of the distances you're interested in. As you read each segment, you subtract the value for the oldest segment, add the new segment value, recompute the average speed, and update the max speed if appropriate.

The algorithm will require you to look at (n^2-n)/2 individual splits. Regardless of how you do it, you have to look at every possible split for every distance you want to compute. You have n data points and you're trying to determine n different best split times. That's O(n^2) any way you slice it.

But the amount of data you're talking about isn't huge, certainly not by today's standards. A marathon is only 42,165 meters. You'll need an array of 422 distances if you want 100-meter resolution. And your code will do on the order of 178,084 calculations. That's quite doable with even a low-end computer these days.

As for the data, I would recommend either pre-processing the .gpx file to generate a stream of data points that are exactly 100 meters. You can do that separately, or you can do it as part of reading the data in while you're computing the splits. It's not difficult, and it'll make the rest of your code much easier to work with.

Comment: I guess I'll have to go with that, at least for a first pass. The actual tracks have way more points because some GPSes record a track-point per second. (while others optimize by not logging points that are in a straight line at constant speed)

So for a 5 hour marathon by a beginner I'm looking at 18K datapoints, or about 162 million potential start-end pairs. Still not daunting for a modern computer I guess. I can preprocess  and reduce that by a couple orders of magnitude if needed I guess. Thank you for the answer!